# How to grant permission to make Azure Release Pipeline to link with Azure App Service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I created CI/CD in Azure DevOps. I connected the CD with Azure service connection as seen in the image. The very last step is to link App service name to my existing app service. However, it doesn't show in the list dropdown box. Even though I tried to enter the name manually, the Deployment failed with the error: Resource 'my-app-service-name' doesn't exist. Resource should exist before deployment.

[image]

In my App service->Deployment Center. I have connected my Azure Repository and my branch successfully.

I tried to add permission (Contributor roles) in my Azure Subscription but it doesn't seem to resolve my issue. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one Service principal and assigned it a contributor role at Subscription level.

[image]

[image]

The assignment is inherited at the Web app level like below:-

[image]

Created service connection by adding its Client Id and Client secret like below:-

[image]

[image]

Then ***I selected Azure App Service Deploy task  version 4 and selected my above created service connection***, Refer below:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much SiddheshDesai for your answer, Somehow the image doesn't load properly. Could you please double check since I really need to see your image to follow through?

Comment: @Sakvin I have edited my answer with images again, Its loading for me. Make sure you are not connected to any LAN or VPN with restrictions, Example- corporate LAN. Are the images visible now?

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm! Thank you for the instruction on how to accept your answer, too.